# Injecting Runtime Objects Using Lamar

Tags: c#, lamar

I'm trying to build a package for Lamar for a framework which I maintain.
To show what I mean by reference to StructureMap, the relevant method which was able to mix a runtime object with Service abstractions is (where the container is passed in to the constructor of this factory class):

```
public IPresenter Create(Type presenterType, Type viewType, IView viewInstance)
{
    container.Configure(x => x.For(presenterType)
        .Use(presenterType)
        .Named(presenterType.Name)
        );

    var args = new ExplicitArguments();
    args.Set("view");
    args.SetArg("view", viewInstance);

    return (IPresenter)container.GetInstance(presenterType, args);
}
```

I realise that Lamar does not implement `ExplicitArguments` (fair enough).

I played around with the Injectable feature, but was no able to get that to work:

```
public IPresenter Create(Type presenterType, Type viewType, IView viewInstance)
{
    var c = _container.GetNestedContainer();
    c.Inject(viewInstance);

    // return c.GetInstance(presenterType, presenterType.Name.ToString()) as IPresenter; // BOOM!!!

    return _container.GetInstance(presenterType) as IPresenter; // BOOM!!!
}
```

Is there an alternative way in Lamar?

This is my registration code:

```
IContainer container = new Container(c =>
{
    c.AddTransient<ISomeService, SomeService>();
    c.Injectable<IMainView>();
    c.AddTransient<MainPresenter>();
});
```

I have created a sample project which recreates the issue which can be [downloaded here](https://app.box.com/s/vtnfh3506nx8jyhufche7ny642v8ma6p). It uses .NET 5

In that project, if you put a break-point in the class `MainPresenter`, you will see that the `IView` parameter is null and the `OrdersService` does resolve.

I need that concrete object, which is the main form, to be passed in as well (as the `IView`).

Cheers

Comment: I seem to have got this working with the above code. The mistake that I was making was that I was registering the injectable as IView instead of the interface which inherited from IView, namely IMainView. So, `c.Injectable<IMainView>();`

Comment: I have spoken too soon. This does not work. The IView is null when the IPresenter is resolved. I've updated the answer with the registration code which I am using.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Also see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616). What exactly do you mean by "BOOM!!!"? Do you get an exception?

Comment: @Progman I have added a link to a zip file with a sample project which recreates the issue. I was initially getting an exception and forgot to remove the references to BOOM when I posted the question. Thanks.

Comment: Do not add the source code on an external site, add the MCVE to the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

there is a problem with `LamarPresenterFactory.Create` method `viewInstance` parameter

```cs
public IPresenter Create(Type presenterType, Type viewType, IView viewInstance)
{
}
```

I've noticed that it should be of `IMainView` type like below

```cs
public IPresenter Create(Type presenterType, Type viewType, IMainView viewInstance)
{
    var nestedContainer = _container.GetNestedContainer();
    nestedContainer.Inject(viewInstance);

    return nestedContainer.GetInstance(presenterType) as IPresenter;
}
```

`nestedContainer.Inject(viewInstance)` parameter data type requires `viewInstance` to be the same type that was used with `c.Injectable<IMainView>();`

I'm getting `OrdersService.GetOrders` exception since there is no `orders.zip` file available

Comment: `IMainView` inherits `IView`. Unfortunately, that parameter has to be IView, otherwise we'd have to write a Create method for every presenter. And the Create method is from a general interface which all supported DI containers implement (only 2 so far). I originally tried registering with `c.Injectable<IView>();` , but an exception is thrown at the call for `GetInstance`.

Comment: @onefootswill it looks wierd since you are declaring to `IMainView` to be injected but whant to get `IView` instance injected instead. It may cause `Create` will get `IView` parameter instance (not `IMainView`) and how do you think container will inject `IView` to the `presenterType` instead of `IMainView`? You may configure container as `c.Injectable<IView>();` and this allow to inject `IView` instance into presenterType constructor.

Comment: It looks like Lamar does not have the capability that I am after yet. If you look at the top of my post, it was possible with StructureMap. The `ExplicitArguments` are configured right there and then in the `Create` method. I've also implemented it with `SimpleInjector` and `Autofac`, who both have different, yet effective, ways of doing it. It's no big deal. I'll support as many IOC frameworks as I can. If Lamar supports it in the future, I'll add support. If it does now and someone can show me how, likewise. Lamar looks great, so I'll definitely support it if I can. Cheers.